# ElasticSearch: How to move a field to a different level with existing data?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6

Say I have:

```
PUT /test/_doc/1
{
    "user" : "kimchy",
    "post_date" : "2009-11-15T14:12:12",
    "message" : "trying out Elasticsearch",
    "data": {
        "modified_date": "2018-11-15T14:12:12",
        "password": "abcpassword"
    }
}
```

Then I get the following mapping:

```
GET /test/_mapping/_doc
{
    "test": {
        "mappings": {
            "_doc": {
                "properties": {
                    "data": {
                        "properties": {
                            "modfied_date": {
                                "type": "date"
                            },
                            "password": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "fields": {
                                    "keyword": {
                                        "type": "keyword",
                                        "ignore_above": 256
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "message": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "post_date": {
                        "type": "date"
                    },
                    "user": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I reindex the mapping to bring `modified_date` to the same level as `user` and not lose any data?

```
{
    "user" : "kimchy",
    "post_date" : "2009-11-15T14:12:12",
    "message" : "trying out Elasticsearch",
    "modified_date": "2018-11-15T14:12:12"
    "data": {
        "password": "abcpassword"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest using [Ingest Node](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest.html) and [Pipelines](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/pipeline.html). You can read about them in the links added respectively.

Basically what I will do is, construct a `pipeline` and mention it during `indexing` or `reindexing` process so that your document would go through *the pre-processing as defined in the pipeline* before document is actually stored in the destination index.

I've created below pipeline for your use case. What it does is, adds a new field `modified_date` with value as required and removed field `data.modified_date`. If any fields are not mentioned in it, it would not be modified and would be ingested in destination index as is.

### Create/Add Pipeline

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/mydatepipeline
{
  "description" : "modified date pipeline",
  "processors" : [
    {
      "set" : {
        "field": "modified_date",
        "value": "{{data.modified_date}}"
      }
    },
    {
      "remove": {
        "field": "data.modified_date"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Once above pipeline is created, make use of it to perform reindexing.

### Usage 1: During Reindexing to New Index

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "test"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "test_dest",
    "pipeline": "mydatepipeline"
  }
}
```

The documents would be transformed as what you expect it to be and would be indexed in `test_dest` index. Note that you need to explicitly create the `test_dest` with the mapping details as per your requirement.

### Usage 2: Using pipeline during bulk operations before indexing

You can use it during bulk operation as follows:

```
POST _bulk?pipeline=mydatepipeline
```

### Usage 3: Using the pipeline on individual docs during indexing

```
PUT test/_doc/1?pipeline=mydatepipeline
{
  "user" : "kimchy",
  "post_date" : "2009-11-15T14:12:12",
  "message" : "trying out Elasticsearch",
  "data": {
      "modified_date": "2018-11-15T14:12:12",
      "password": "abcpassword"
  }
}
```

For both `Usage 2 and 3`, you need to ensure your mapping is created accordingly.

Hope this helps!